# gcc -O2 vs. without causes error

Tags: c, linux, gcc

When compiling file containing `open("FILENAME", O_RDONLY);` without `-O2` flag everything is fine. But when `-O2` is turned on I get:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h: In function ‘open’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:44:7: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:45:26: error: call to ‘__open_too_many_args’ declared with attribute error: open can be called either with 2 or 3 arguments, not more
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:42:1: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:60:3: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h: In function ‘open64’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:76:7: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:77:28: error: call to ‘__open64_too_many_args’ declared with attribute error: open64 can be called either with 2 or 3 arguments, not more
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:74:1: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:92:3: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h: In function ‘openat’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:120:7: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:121:28: error: call to ‘__openat_too_many_args’ declared with attribute error: openat can be called either with 3 or 4 arguments, not more
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:118:1: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:136:3: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h: In function ‘openat64’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:154:7: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:155:30: error: call to ‘__openat64_too_many_args’ declared with attribute error: openat64 can be called either with 3 or 4 arguments, not more
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:152:1: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack_len ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:170:3: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
```

Where can be the problem? It's mixed `C/C++` project but this is in the `C` part. gcc 4.6.1, kernel 3.0.0

**Edit:** It turns out that commeting out those line gives another "type" of errors like:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘sprintf’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:34:3: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide a minimal yet complete code example that triggers this error?

Comment: Strange, are you sure it comes from this line ? Do you include everything needed ? (for open and O_RDONLY)

Comment: So do you call `g++` or `gcc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try compiling with `-fno-builtins`. If that fixes it then you've obviously got some sort of problem, but it's probably not in your source.

Answer (score 8):

I hit this when trying to compile https://www.spec.org/cpu2017/Docs/benchmarks/602.gcc_s.html with GCC.

Ironically, the bootstrap process would fail due to GCC apparently not understanding GNU extensions.

Turning on `-fgnu89-inline` got rid of any problems I was having.
Alternatively, use `-std=gnu89`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply download a different (slightly older?) kernel build:

Here's a bug report, for whatever it's worth:

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/27100

And no, I have *no* idea why "-O2" would have anything to do with this particular error...

ADDENDUM:
This link might give you more explanation about the error message itself.  But again - I'd suggest trying a different kernel build as your first step:

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-09/msg00675.html

Comment: O2 causes errors because when optimizing, the compiler is using those builtin functions. When it isn't optimizing, it is using library functions.

Comment: Generally, some of the code which detects errors belongs to various  optimization passes. Hence the compiler detects these errors only when these passes are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore this error, consider removing the flag `-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` .
For example, if you use `rpmbuild`, this flag is introduced by `RPM_OPT_FLAGS`

```
%build
export CFLAGS="$RPM_OPT_FLAGS"
export CXXFLAGS="$RPM_OPT_FLAGS"
./configure …
```

Here is a simple way to keep everything but the mentioned flag

```
OPT_FLAGS=`echo $RPM_OPT_FLAGS | sed 's/-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 //'`
export CFLAGS="$OPT_FLAGS"
export CXXFLAGS="$OPT_FLAGS"
```