# gcc stdio.h error

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I get these errors when compiling `gcc -c -O2...`:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:930:0,
                 from /home/martin/foo.c:3:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘sprintf’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:34:3: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘snprintf’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:65:3: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
```

It occurs only when `-O2` is turned on, gcc 4.6.1. What can be wrong? I've checked all header guards and they seem OK.

Comment: What is your distribution? What is your `foo.c` program? Is the `gcc` the one packaged by your distribution?

Comment: Can you please show the whole command line as there's a good chance that there's a -D or similar missing.

Comment: Does this happen if the source file you compile consists of _just_ '`#include <stdio.h>`'?  If not, what do you need to add to make it happen?

Comment: why the C++ flag? Everything we see so far suggest that this is C, no?

Comment: It could be a mismatch between your gcc and your glibc.  *Show us the source file and the full command you used to compile it.*

Comment: Related: [gcc-O2-vs-without-causes-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494392/gcc-o2-vs-without-causes-error)

Comment: You should post the program that caused this problem or nobody is going to be able to debug it.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a good reason for using `-O2`? Will `-O` [or `-O1`] do instead of `-O2`. If you really need to use `-O2` and wish narrow down the 'culprit flag', one suggestion is to use `-O1` and then turn on `gcc` flags one by one that is used for `-O2`. Here is a list of flags used by `-O2`.

```
      -fthread-jumps 
      -falign-functions  
      -falign-jumps 
      -falign-loops  
      -falign-labels 
      ... // there is a big list
```

You can find these flags in [gcc manual on optimization's](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). The manual should give detailed explanation of each flag and its purpose.

Comment: *None* of gcc's `-O` levels are equivalent to any combination of `-f` switches (more precisely, they all do *more* than just setting a bunch of `-f` switches).